# How can I get URL parameters passed to a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I access the parameters passed to a Google Docs spreadsheet in Google Apps Script? I do not seem to be able to access `window.location.search`, and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getURL()` returns the official URI of the document without any user-added parameters.

I am trying to pass in a sheet name that can be accessed by `onOpen()`, so that I can link to sheets by name rather than order of creation (gID). `doGet` for services can receive access request parameters, but that does not help here...

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible today. As you noted, `doGet`, `doPost` are the ones that can grab the variables when deployed as a web app.

Please log an enhancement on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)