# How can I pass a variable to spreadsheet function?

Tags: google-apps-script

**Here is what I'm trying to do:**

Embed a Google spreadsheet in my website in multiple locations. For registered users, I want to show all the data in the spreadsheet. For unregistered users, I want to hide key numbers.

I have a spreadsheet with a custom function called blackOut(). I've put the blackOut function in all of the cells with sensitive data. All blackOut() need to do is this:

```
function blackOut(e) {
  var is registered = ??
  if (is_registered) return e;
  else return "";
}
```

But I cant find any way to 'pass' any variables from my website to the function, so I haven't been able to make it work.

**Here's my environment:**

In PHP I'm using cURL to get the spreadsheet's embed code from this URL:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=[spreadsheet ID]&output=html&widget=true

then I'm doing a few str_replace functions to make the JS and CSS work.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- using window.location in my function (doesn't work. Google doesn't let you access window)
- passing a javascript variable in globally (in JS global variables are technically attached to the window object)
- using SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getURL() (just returns the URL for the spreadsheet, not the one that existed in the http request)
- looking through all of the available objects in Google Code

**My Ideal Solution:**

It would be great if I could just add '&blackout=true' to the URL, and pass that into blackOut() in the google script. I've looked around a lot, and I don't think it's possible.

**I've looked at these links:**

- [How can I get URL parameters passed to a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434309/getting-url-parameters-in-google-apps-script)
- [Alternative to global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062564/alternative-to-global-variables)
- [GAS: Problems in using global variables in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106723/gas-problems-in-using-global-variables-in-functions)

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm understanding your question wrong, but am i to understand that you are not using a iframe or viewing the sheet directly? You are using a published url and from there you get your data. You already do some custom conversion to the HTML (so you have the knowledge and tools to edit your data/html yourself).

Could you go a small step further and create the whole html table yourself?
Then you could use the query functionality of google spreadsheets (url query parameters).
This way you could validate the users from your site and do two different data query's.
One with all the columns, one without some columns.

For example see: http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=4001

For the google language reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: I thought about doing it that way originally. I could have just added changed "&format=html" to "&format=csv", and spit out the data in a HTML table. My problem with that solution is that I would lose the formatting (colors etc) of the spreadsheet, and I want to give as much control to my client as possible. I want my client to be able to edit the spreadsheet through Google Docs, and have those changes show up on the website.

Comment: Well, in that case google does'nt offer that option in a published sheet. What you could do (as a workaround) is create a second sheet with the importRange function. The same idea applies. The original with all columns, the second with some omitted. Then publish both versions.

Comment: Ok, does importRange also import styling?

Comment: No, because you create a second spreadsheet that uses this function, you create a spreadsheet where the content changes with the sheet it's connected to. i.e. you could make an identical copy with identical styling of the original (source spreadsheet) or even do some different styling. That's just one of the additional benefits of this approach. It's a completely different (published) spreadsheet but the data range is linked. If you also want (dynamicly) change colors and styling you're asking to much.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Upvoting your answer. Thanks for helping :)